# Bootstrap class name telling that this col will be 5-width for md and inferior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My example is there:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
```

Is there a way not to specify `sm`, `xs`, and just assume if I declare `col-md-5`, and I don't declare any lower resolution, it should be 5 too???

I find it kind of heavy having to write all resolution for all tags, even if they are the same...

Tx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your observation is true. you can do it. but there is one little difference.Bootstrap using their CSS style from Min-width to MAX. so if you want to keep lower resolution for same width then your code must be as below.

your current code -> `<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-7 "></div>`

Instead of this you can write below code

`<div class="col-xs-5 col-lg-7 "></div>`

Comment: it's true! Working fine as you said ! Tx